# How to override css style of shadow dom

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom, fluent, fluent-ui

I am using the fluent ui web component for autocomplete drop-down. I want to change the background of the drop-down box but there is a #shadow-root(open) created which I am not able to override. So please help me how to override this shadow dom.

I attached the image of my inspect where I want to override .control class inside the #shadow-root
[image]

Comment: Can you edit shadow root content?

Comment: No I am not able to edit shadow root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div content has part attribute. It make your work done.
Add this line in your css file

```
fluent-combobox::part(control) {
    //add your css properties
}
```

Read more at [MDN ::part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part)